# How to refresh my fragments in Viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-viewpager, refresh

I'm using ViewPager with Action Bar. On the Action Bar there are some component, for example delete button. My application is a gallery app, and I would like to delete the selected pictures. It's works, but I don't know how to refresh my fragment in order to disappear deleted pictures from gridview.

I try to make it for a long time, and It would be very important for me.

Thanks for your help.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private static final int FOLDER = 0;
private static final int TEXT_ID = 0;
private static final String PATH_OF_FILES = "/Pictures/";
File folder;
ViewPager Tab;
TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;



ArrayList<ImageItem> listOfFiles = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();

private String dirToMove = "";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    listOfFiles = FileListerUtil.getFilesFromDirectory(PATH_OF_FILES);


    TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Tab = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
    Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });
    Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
    actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                FragmentTransaction ft) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    };


    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Pic")
            .setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Other")
            .setTabListener(tabListener));





}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_action, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {


     case R.id.action_remove:




                    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.size(); i++) {
                        if (listOfFiles.get(i).isChecked()) {

                            File file = new File(listOfFiles.get(i).getImagePath());


                                file.delete();
                                }

                        }


            return true;


     default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}



public ArrayList<ImageItem> getListOfFiles() {
    return listOfFiles;
}

public void setListOfFiles(ArrayList<ImageItem> listOfFiles) {
    this.listOfFiles = listOfFiles;
}

public String getDirToMove() {
    return dirToMove;
}

public void setDirToMove(String dirToMove) {
    this.dirToMove = dirToMove;
}

public static boolean copyFile(String from, String to) {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            int end = from.toString().lastIndexOf("/");
            String str1 = from.toString().substring(0, end);
            String str2 = from.toString().substring(end+1, from.length());
            File source = new File(str1, str2);
            File destination= new File(to, str2);
            if (source.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**FragmentStateAdapter:**

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
super(fm);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


 }
  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:

        return new Pictures();
    case 1:

        return new Albums();

    }
return null;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 2; //No of Tabs
}

public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

**Pictures:**

```
public class Pictures extends Fragment{
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

private int count;
private Bitmap[] thumbnails;

private String[] arrPath;
private Context context;



ArrayList<ImageItem> fileListParam = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, menu);
}





public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    boolean[] checkState;
    private LayoutInflater inflat;
    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<ImageItem> itemList = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();




    public ImageAdapter(ArrayList<ImageItem> files, Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        inflat = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.itemList = files;


    }



    void clear() {
        itemList.clear();
    }

    void remove(int index) {
        itemList.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;

        // reuse views
        if (rowView == null) {

            rowView = inflat.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            // configure view holder
            final ViewHolderPictures viewHolderPictures = new ViewHolderPictures();
            viewHolderPictures.imageview = (ImageView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            viewHolderPictures.checkbox = (CheckBox) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

            viewHolderPictures.imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_border);
            viewHolderPictures.imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            viewHolderPictures.imageview.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);





            rowView.setTag(viewHolderPictures);
        }

        // fill data
        ViewHolderPictures holder = (ViewHolderPictures) rowView.getTag();

        holder.checkbox
        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0,
                    boolean arg1) {
                itemList.get(position).setChecked(arg1);


            }
        });


        final Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromMemCache(itemList.get(position)
                .getImagePath());
        if (bm == null) {
            BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(holder.imageview);
            task.execute(itemList.get(position).getImagePath());
        }
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(itemList.get(position).isChecked());

        return rowView;


    }
}

public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {

    Bitmap bm = null;
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    return bm;
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}



public class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage
        // collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        final Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(params[0], 140,
                120);
        addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(params[0]), bitmap);
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageViewReference
                    .get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }


}



int fragVal;
ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;



static Pictures init(int val) {
    Pictures truitonFrag = new Pictures();
    // Supply val input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("val", val);
    truitonFrag.setArguments(args);
    return truitonFrag;
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fragVal = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    final int memClass = ((ActivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
            Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();


    // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
    final int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 8;

    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {

        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            // The cache size will be measured in bytes rather than number
            // of items.
            return bitmap.getByteCount();
        }

    };


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Gridview gridview;
    View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kepgrid, container, false);
    gridview = (GridView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.gv_photolist);



    ArrayList<ImageItem> files = ((MainActivity) getActivity())
            .getListOfFiles();

    context = getActivity();
    myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(files, context);
    gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);



    return layoutView;
}




public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return (Bitmap) mMemoryCache.get(key);
}
}
```